# Samsung M393B2K70DM0-YF8 is not recognized by my PC

Tags: memory

I have this RAM:

https://www.itcreations.com/view_product.asp?product_id=32310

and few similar ones. Friend of mine worked in an IT warehouse and they were supposed to throw them away, so he taken out some for himself. I tried to insert it to my home desktop, which has a pretty good spec, apart from the quite old GA-78LMT-USB3 motherboard. My PC would not recognise this RAM.

I made some research that such RAMS are used in High End workstations etc. Does anyone know what could be the reason for that? I mean bottom line is, the device may simply not work at all, but I wanted to exclude any other possibilities. Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does anyone know what could be the reason for that?

Your [motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.us/Motherboard/GA-78LMT-USB3-rev-50#sp) doesn't support ECC memory.

> 4 x 1.5V DDR3 DIMM sockets supporting up to 32 GB of system memory
>   (Note 1) Dual channel memory architecture Support for
>   1600(O.C.)/1333/1066 MHz memory modules

While the memory you purchased is indeed ECC memory:

> SAMSUNG 16GB PC3L-8500R DDR3-1066 REGISTERED ECC MEMORY MODULE
>   M393B2K70DM0-YF8

[Samsung M393B2K70DM0-YF8](https://www.itcreations.com/view_product.asp?product_id=32310)

Solution: Purchase non-ECC from the [supported memory list](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Memory/mb_memory_ga-78lmt-usb3.pdf) generated by Gigabyte for your motherboard.  You can get different brands, not listed in the linked .pdf, but select memory based on supported voltage and frequency of similar modules that are in the list.